Create an automation using Power Automate to clear all the filter in a table for an excel file in sharepoint without using scripts
I have a flow in Power Automate that creates a new excel file based in another file that is in sharepoint, but if the file in sharepoint is filtered does not return all the rows, just the filtered rows and I need all the rows in the new file so I am trying to find a way to clear all the filters in the automation before the step "list all the rows".
I tried to create a macro in the file to clear all the filters when it's opened and closed, but as the file is in the cloud and it is a shared file, people can also open in the browser and the macro doesn't work everytime.

Not possible without using Office Script.
As an alternative, suggest having a duplicated table in a second sheet and use that in your Flow. You can hide this sheet in Excel. If folks are editing the table then you could look to use Power Query to read-in that table and output it to a new sheet (hidden etc...).

Thanks for your help, I did that, it was the only way that I found to solve this issue.
